# Divide dataset classes for ML binary classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, classification

```
data_dir = '/kaggle/input/'
my_data_dir = f'{data_dir}/surface-crack-detection/surface-crack-detection/'
positive_dir = my_data_dir + 'Positive/'
negative_dir = my_data_dir + 'Negative/'
        
# Define image dimensions
img_height, img_width = 224, 224
batch_size = 32

# Create ImageDataGenerators without data augmentation
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    my_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='training'
)

validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    my_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='validation'
)
```

I have the two folders **Positive** and **Negative**.
The problem is that if I print the following:

```
for i in range(len(validation_generator)):
    batch = next(validation_generator)
    images, labels = batch
    file_paths = validation_generator.filepaths[i * batch_size:(i + 1) * batch_size]
    
    for j in range(len(file_paths)):
        print(f"File Path: {file_paths[j]}, Label: {labels[j]}")
```

I get:

```
File Path: /kaggle/input//surface-crack-detection/surface-crack-detection/Negative/N00001.jpg, Label: 1.0
File Path: /kaggle/input//surface-crack-detection/surface-crack-detection/Negative/N00002.jpg, Label: 1.0
File Path: /kaggle/input//surface-crack-detection/surface-crack-detection/Negative/N00003.jpg, Label: 1.0
File Path: /kaggle/input//surface-crack-detection/surface-crack-detection/Negative/N00004.jpg, Label: 1.0
File Path: /kaggle/input//surface-crack-detection/surface-crack-detection/Negative/N00005.jpg, Label: 0.0
File Path: /kaggle/input//surface-crack-detection/surface-crack-detection/Negative/N00006.jpg, Label: 0.0
File Path: /kaggle/input//surface-crack-detection/surface-crack-detection/Negative/N00007.jpg, Label: 1.0
File Path: /kaggle/input//surface-crack-detection/surface-crack-detection/Negative/N00008.jpg, Label: 0.0
File Path: /kaggle/input//surface-crack-detection/surface-crack-detection/Negative/N00009.jpg, Label: 0.0
File Path: /kaggle/input//surface-crack-detection/surface-crack-detection/Negative/N00010.jpg, Label: 0.0
File Path: /kaggle/input//surface-crack-detection/surface-crack-detection/Negative/N00011.jpg, Label: 1.0
File Path: /kaggle/input//surface-crack-detection/surface-crack-detection/Negative/N00012.jpg, Label: 1.0
```

Which means that the label is wrong. The label should be coherent with the name of the folder: for negative folder, the label must always be 0, while for positive folder, label must be always 1.

What am I mistaking?

Comment: Your code is incorrect, filepaths inside the generator are not in the same order as you iterate the generator (there is shuffling involved), which is why your labels make no sense.

Comment: Yes I figured out at the end. I set shuffle=False and it worked. Thank you very much